# Do constant transformations count in matrix rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

So the definition of matrix rank is number of "linearly independent" rows or columns.  However it seems like adding a scalar to a row to get to another row does not count as linear dependence?  For example, we have two rows:

r1: [6, 3, 1]

r2: [7, 4, 2]

This has a rank of 2 as the two above are linearly independent, even though we could add 1 to r1 to get r2.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, it is true that these two rows are linearly independent

Comment: Thanks.  That's a confusing definition.

Comment: It might help if you remember the reason for these definitions: if we are solving a system of equations, it makes sense to multiply the equation $x + 2y + 3z = 1$ by a number to get $2x + 4y + 6z = 2$, but it does not make sense to add a number to all coefficients to get $2x + 3y + 4z = 2$.